# How to pass data from parent window to child popup window

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, client

I'm newer in web programming so maybe my question will seem naive to some of you, I need to pass data from parent window to child popup window.

I found in google only opposite examples(i.e passing data from child to parent).

I will appreciate if you could share with example, or short explanation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the popup is a child, then you should have no problem to set the data to it, i.e. let's say the popup is a `popup` object in the window class/scene, you can simply implement a function like `setText` and pass there the data from parent. It would be way easier to discuss this if you shared your code/structure here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the popup you open abides by the [Same-Origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) you have full access to the document. And then you can just do something like this:

```
var child = window.open('about:blank'),
    something = document.createElement('div');

something.innerHTML = "<h2>Something!</h2>";

child.document.body.appendChild(something);
```